# Summation function in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

I tried using this:

SQRT( SUM( POWER(C3:C22  - 378.9, 2) )/20)

But I am getting 17.4, But STDEV.S gives ~72.46

Here are datapoints:

175
373
304
411
411
384
457
330
362
448
394
403
420
377
513
374
392
425
364
261

Comment: `STDEV.S` uses a [different formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-S-function-7d69cf97-0c1f-4acf-be27-f3e83904cc23).

Comment: @GSerg which one is the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is the same one used by `STDEV.P`. However, you should press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when you are on the cell of your formula because it is an array formula. You should get 70.63.

If you divide by 19 (instead of 20), you'll get the result of `STDEV.S`